# Fill with blanks only if empty

Tags: google-sheets

I want to fill the column which is named as "Country Final".
Logic is like this:

1. Choose the values from "Country" column.
2. If the cell from "Country" column is empty, pick values from "Country(L)" column.
3. If both are empty, keep it empty.

[image: Screenshot of Google Sheet]

I have no idea how should I go about this.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the following formula to T2:

```
=IF(O2<>"",O2,S2)
```

Drag down it to fill the other cells.

Answer (score 0):

You have sort filters on your columns, so you are going to have to use a particular kind of array formula.

Delete the header from T1 and make sure T:T is completely empty. Then place the following formula in T1:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(O:O)=1,"Country Final",IF(O:O<>"",O:O,IF(S:S="",,S:S))))`

This will produce the header and all column results while allowing you to continue to use the column sorting feature.

Comment: The aporoach in `T1` is a good one but  the formula can be simplified by about 20 characters by eliminating 2 unnecessary conditions: `=ARRAYFORMULA({"Country Final";IF(02:O<>"",02:0,S2:S)})` **1.** The test for the formula's row is not needed.
**2.** The test of `S2:S` is not needed. Whenever `O2:O` is blank, `S2:S` will  **always** contain the required value regardless if it's blank or not. I think this is an improvement, rather than a sepperate answer, but wanted your okay prior to editing.